# eCommerce Tracking Issues in google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   dataLayer = [];
    dataLayer.push({
        'transactionId'            : '27628SB013442',
        'transactionTotal'        : 4760.00,
        'transactionTax'        : 480.32,
        'transactionProducts'    : [{
            'sku'        : '27328SB013442 - 7/1/2016',
            'name'        : 'Client Name',
            'category'    : 'GV1K',
            'price'        : 595.00,
            'quantity'    : 8
        }]
    });
   dataLayer.push({
      'event':'checkout',
      'virtualPageURL':'/order-status',
      'virtualPageTitle':'confirmation'
});
</script>
        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer',"GTM-XXXXXX");</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Above is my static dataLayer code snippet. I have created an event named "checkout" in GTM account. But it is not affecting in analytics overview section. Is anything wrong in my code?

EDIT: DataLayer has been updated to this:

```
dataLayer = []
dataLayer.push({
   'event':'checkout', 
   'transactionType' : 'demo purpose', 
   'transactionId' : '27628SB013442', 
   'transactionTotal': 4760.00,
   'transactionTax' : 480.32,
   'transactionProducts' : [{
      'sku' : '27328SB013442 - 7/1/2016', 
      'name' : 'Client Name', 
      'category' : 'GV1K',
      'price' : 595.00,
      'quantity' : 8
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to push the `checkout` event with your e-commerce data, and make sure you use a Transaction type tag to read the data, since this isn't an enhanced e-commerce transaction. Also verify with GA Debugger or in the dev console that you can see the hit. Other than that I think it looks fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @nyuen for your quick reply. Now my dataLayer is -
`dataLayer = [];  dataLayer.push({
'event':'checkout',
'transactionType' : 'demo purpose',
'transactionId'   : '27628SB013442',
'transactionTotal': 4760.00,
'transactionTax'  : 480.32,
'transactionProducts' : [{
     'sku'        : '27328SB013442 - 7/1/2016',
     'name'        : 'Client Name',
     'category'    : 'GV1K',
     'price'        : 595.00,
     'quantity'    : 8
}]
});`
I didn't find any `transactionType` tag in documentation I have passed a demo value. Now is it right?

Comment: No, that won't work. You need to use a `transaction type` tag. See my screenshot. What you've done is just add a parameter that GA won't recognise.